# The Excel File gets corrupted when it gets downloaded

Tags: c#, excel, .net-core

I am using [Syncfusion](https://nuget.syncfusion.com/dashboard/package/aspnetcore)  library  to create excell file in Asp.Net Core2.2 . the problem is that when I create an Api to Download the created Excell file, it gets corrupted and when I try to open it with MS Excell it says that the file format and the file extension does not match. here is my code for Creating Excell and My Api:

```
 [HttpGet] public IActionResult Excel () {
            using (ExcelEngine excelEngine = new ExcelEngine ()) {
                //Instantiate the Excel application object
                IApplication application = excelEngine.Excel;

                //Assigns default application version
                application.DefaultVersion = ExcelVersion.Excel2013;

                //A new workbook is created equivalent to creating a new workbook in Excel
                //Create a workbook with 1 worksheet
                IWorkbook workbook = application.Workbooks.Create (1);

                //Access a worksheet from workbook
                IWorksheet worksheet = workbook.Worksheets[0];

                //Adding text data
                worksheet.Range["A1"].Text = "Month";
                worksheet.Range["B1"].Text = "Sales";
                worksheet.Range["A6"].Text = "Total";

                //Adding DateTime data
                worksheet.Range["A2"].DateTime = new DateTime (2015, 1, 10);
                worksheet.Range["A3"].DateTime = new DateTime (2015, 2, 10);
                worksheet.Range["A4"].DateTime = new DateTime (2015, 3, 10);

                //Applying number format for date value cells A2 to A4
                worksheet.Range["A2:A4"].NumberFormat = "mmmm, yyyy";

                //Auto-size the first column to fit the content
                worksheet.AutofitColumn (1);

                //Adding numeric data
                worksheet.Range["B2"].Number = 68878;
                worksheet.Range["B3"].Number = 71550;
                worksheet.Range["B4"].Number = 72808;

                //Adding formula
                worksheet.Range["B6"].Formula = "SUM(B2:B4)";
                var name = Guid.NewGuid() + ".xlsx";

                //Inserting image

                //Saving the workbook to disk in XLSX format
                FileStream fileStream = new FileStream (name, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite); // Copy file stream to MemoryStream.
                MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream ();
                fileStream.CopyTo (memoryStream);
                // Gets byte array from memory stream of file.
                byte[] temp = memoryStream.ToArray ();
                excelEngine.Dispose();
                return File (temp, "application/ms-excel", name);
            }


        }
```

Comment: You create a workbook, where do you save it? All I can see is you later create an empty file and then copy it to a memory stream and return the contents - which I'd expect to be empty.

Comment: As Charles said, you aren't saving the Excel file anywhere. Furthermore, I'm not sure you want `FileMode.Create`, even if the file did exist.

Comment: thanks for your responses. how should I save the workbook in FileStream?

Comment: I'd suggest you take a look at [the docs](https://help.syncfusion.com/file-formats/xlsio/loading-and-saving-workbook?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=asp.net%20core#saving-a-excel-workbook-to-stream).

Answer (score 1):

**The final code That works Properly thanks to the kind help of others:**

```
[HttpPost] public IActionResult Excel () {
            using (ExcelEngine excelEngine = new ExcelEngine ()) {
                //Instantiate the Excel application object
                IApplication application = excelEngine.Excel;

                //Assigns default application version
                application.DefaultVersion = ExcelVersion.Excel2013;

                //A new workbook is created equivalent to creating a new workbook in Excel
                //Create a workbook with 1 worksheet
                IWorkbook workbook = application.Workbooks.Create (1);

                //Access a worksheet from workbook
                IWorksheet worksheet = workbook.Worksheets[0];

                //Adding text data
                worksheet.Range["A1"].Text = "Month";
                worksheet.Range["B1"].Text = "Sales";
                worksheet.Range["A6"].Text = "Total";

                //Adding DateTime data
                worksheet.Range["A2"].DateTime = new DateTime (2015, 1, 10);
                worksheet.Range["A3"].DateTime = new DateTime (2015, 2, 10);
                worksheet.Range["A4"].DateTime = new DateTime (2015, 3, 10);

                //Applying number format for date value cells A2 to A4
                worksheet.Range["A2:A4"].NumberFormat = "mmmm, yyyy";

                //Auto-size the first column to fit the content
                worksheet.AutofitColumn (1);

                //Adding numeric data
                worksheet.Range["B2"].Number = 68878;
                worksheet.Range["B3"].Number = 71550;
                worksheet.Range["B4"].Number = 72808;

                //Adding formula
                worksheet.Range["B6"].Formula = "SUM(B2:B4)";
                var name = Guid.NewGuid () + ".xlsx";
                // FileStream inputStream = new FileStream (name, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite);
                string ContentType = "Application/msexcel";
                MemoryStream outputStream = new MemoryStream ();
                workbook.SaveAs (outputStream);
                outputStream.Position = 0;
                return File (outputStream, ContentType, name);
            }

        }
```